# Issue in connecting to Oracle DB while the load is very high

Tags: oracle, jboss

I am getting the below error from jboss server when the load in the application is very high. When this error comes the application didnt process any request after a few times the connection resets and application resumes.

```
DEBUG Periodic recovery - first pass <Tue, 7 Feb 2017 13:01:59>
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:01:59,029] DEBUG StatusModule: first pass 
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:01:59,029] DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.internal.txoj.recovery.TORecoveryModule_3] - TORecoveryModule - first pass
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:01:59,030] DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.info.firstpass] Local XARecoveryModule - first pass
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:02:09,030] DEBUG Periodic recovery - second pass <Tue, 7 Feb 2017 13:02:09>
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:02:09,030] DEBUG AtomicActionRecoveryModule: Second pass 
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:02:09,030] DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.internal.txoj.recovery.TORecoveryModule_6] - TORecoveryModule - second pass
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:02:09,030] DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery`enter code here`.info.secondpass] Local XARecoveryModule - second pass
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:02:09,030] DEBUG Recover java:/DefaultJMSProvider
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:02:09,031] DEBUG ********************************Failed to connect to server
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: XAConnectionFactory not bound
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:726)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.jboss.util.naming.Util.lookup(Util.java:222)
at  org.jboss.jms.server.recovery.MessagingXAResourceWrapper.getConnectionFactory(MessagingXAResourceWrapper.java:393)
at org.jboss.jms.server.recovery.MessagingXAResourceWrapper.connect(MessagingXAResourceWrapper.java:339)
at org.jboss.jms.server.recovery.MessagingXAResourceWrapper.getDelegate(MessagingXAResourceWrapper.java:261)
at org.jboss.jms.server.recovery.MessagingXAResourceWrapper.recover(MessagingXAResourceWrapper.java:108)
at  com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:773)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:665)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:200)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:799)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:412)
[Thread-12] [2017-02-07 13:02:09,031] DEBUG Cannot get delegate XAResource
javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Error trying to connect to provider    java:/DefaultJMSProvider
at  org.jboss.jms.server.recovery.MessagingXAResourceWrapper.getDelegate(MessagingXAResourceWrapper.java:271)
at org.jboss.jms.server.recovery.MessagingXAResourceWrapper.recover(MessagingXAResourceWrapper.java:108)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:773)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:665)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:200)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:799)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:412)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: XAConnectionFactory not bound
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:726)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at org.jboss.util.naming.Util.lookup(Util.java:222)
at  org.jboss.jms.server.recovery.MessagingXAResourceWrapper.getConnectionFactory(MessagingXAResourceWrapper.java:393)
at org.jboss.jms.server.recovery.MessagingXAResourceWrapper.connect(MessagingXAResourceWrapper.java:339)
at org.jboss.jms.server.recovery.MessagingXAResourceWrapper.getDelegate(MessagingXAResourceWrapper.java:261)
```

**after this below warning is also observed**

```
WARN  Destroying connection that is not valid, due to the following  exception: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@43017c6e
java.sql.SQLException: pingDatabase failed status=-2
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker.isValidConnection(OracleValidConnectionChecker.java:74)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.isValidConnection(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:560)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.checkValid(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:323)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.matchManagedConnections(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:402)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:225)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:690)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:404)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:424)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
at com.infosys.fdc.util.ConnectionManager.getConnectionFromPool(ConnectionManager.java:382)
at com.infosys.fdc.util.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:507)
at com.infosys.fdc.ejb.CommonEJBBean.execute(CommonEJBBean.java:165)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:386)
at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:233)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:156)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.java:173)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorBMT.invoke(TxInterceptorBMT.java:77)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:173)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:228)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:211)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.process(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.invoke(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:650)
at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:1092)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:169)
at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:118)
at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeLocal(InvokerInterceptor.java:209)
at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:195)
at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.SecurityContextInterceptor.invoke(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:68)
at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.StatelessSessionInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInterceptor.java:112)
at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:101)
at $Proxy125.execute(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
java.sql.SQLException: pingDatabase failed status=-2
```

This means there is "something" wrong with either the Oracle database itself or with the network.

pingDatabase is a method of oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection and is used by the JBoss OracleValidConnectionChecker to check if a connection to the database is still valid and working.

According to [Oracle Database JBDC Driver API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/constant-values.html) - Constant Field Values, the return codes are:

- DATABASE_OK= 0; // The physical database connection is not closed and the database is reachable. (will not be logged)
- DATABASE_CLOSED= -1; // The physical database connection is closed.
- DATABASE_NOTOK= -2; // The physical database connection is not closed but the database is not reachable.
- DATABASE_TIMEOUT= -3 // The call timed out before any positive or negative acknowledgement was received.
- Test the network with the usual means like ping, telnet, ssh... connection tests.
- Check if your DNS name resolution is working properly; use an IP address instead of a hostname when in doubt.
- Test if connections to the Oracle database are working using the Oracle tnsping utility or with SQL*plus.
  Note: requires a native Oracle client install.
- JBoss is only reporting this error which is coming from the Oracle JDBC driver. The root cause will either be the Oracle database itself, or the network.
- Upgrade the Oracle JDBC driver. We have seen many reports where this fixed the issue. It would seem that the older driver(s) had a bug which could cause return code "-2".
- To get to the root cause, need to work with Oracle since this error is coming from the Oracle driver, and is only being reported by JBoss.
  The error indicates that connectivity was not possible between the JBoss application server and the database
- This is most likely due to a problem with the network or the database server itself. Sometimes, such issues are temporary, however, you will want to engage your network and/or DBA team to review the issue if this issue persists.
- It is highly recommend reaching out to Oracle with the TRACE logs and getting input from them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anup

Answer (score 2):

Computer science 101. Reduce the load on your server. My team has developed some demos to show the impact of large number of connections to your database, and you can see a video of it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzN8Rp6glEo

Comment: Thanku... Thanks a lot :)